# Prefixset on codility using c#

Tags: c#, .net

Problem Description:

> Given a table A of N integers from 0 to N-1 calculate the smallest
>   such index P, that that {A[0],...,A[N-1]} = {A[0],...,A[P]}.

My solution

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        for (int i=A.Length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            int[] Am = A.Take(i).ToArray();
            int pos = Array.IndexOf(Am, A[i]);
            if( pos >- 1 )
            {
            }
            else
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return A.Length-1;
    }
}
```

This works but complexity is O(N**2) and times out when Array has large number of elements

If i use `long` in place of `int`, I get the `cs0266 cannot implicitly convert long to int` error.

Please suggest on how i can improve this. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, where did you get LINQ for .NET 2.0?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Comment: @JohnSaunders Much obliged. I was not aware LINQ cannot be used with 2.0. Then again i'm new to C#

Comment: .NET 2.0 is almost a decade old! Consider upgrading to .NET 3.5, which is precisely .NET 2.0 SP2 plus some additional libraries. No change in CLR. It's safe.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I personally use .NET 4, it's the codility testing environment that has the .NET 2.0

Comment: @Jay: that would be a hint, it would just be a _different_ hint.

Comment: problem description is incomplete. Cannot answer, because P must be equal to N-1, unless "{" means a Set..

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep track of all the elements you have already observed using a set.

```
public Int32 Solution(Int32[] A)
{
   var seenNumbers = new HashSet<Int32>();

   var result = 0;

   for (var index = 0; index < A.Length; index++)
   {
      if (seenNumbers.Add(A[index]))
      {
         result = index;
      }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Note that `HashSet<T>.Add()` will return true if the element is not already in the set, false otherwise. When you discover a number for the first time you obviously have to include that number and therefore extend the prefix to the current position. This will run in `O(n)` and consume `O(n)` additional space.